# Iterate over headings in rich text component in Storyblok

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, storyblok

I'm using `storyblok-nuxt` module. I have a storyblok component with rich text. I'd like to create a sidebar with list of heading that appears in this rich text for navigation purposes. Is there a way to extract those headings from rich text using storyapi, or do I need to do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating "Article" component in Storyblok with *title* and *body* properties, where *body* is my rich text field. Iterating through *titles* is not a problem and in this case I make sure that every Article has a title.